# Different exe sizes when compiling using the Visual C++ Express 2010 IDE and compiling under console with cl command

Tags: c++, c, ide

This is my first question here, i'm a big fan and found many solutions in stackoverflow, so many thanks to all. I would be happy if my question is one that is worth time.

I'm using Windows 7 and Microsft Visual C++ 2010 Express.
The C code is:

```
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

When compiling the code with the ide, with project properties -> C/C++ -> CodeGeneration -> Runtime Library = /MTd option the exe size is 395,264 bytes.
When compiling the program under console with cl.exe using the Visual Studio Command Prompt
"cl test.c" the exe size is 31,744.

SIZES:
1. 395,264
2.  31,744

Any idea why there is so big differences in the sizes?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because:

1. There are many more VC++ compiler options, not just the `/M` family of options.
2. Several of those options can affect the executable's size.
3. The IDE's defaults for a new project are different than the defaults of the compiler and linker themselves.

Somewhere in the IDE, go to your test project's properties. Open *Configuration Properties* -> *C/C++* -> *Command Line* and *Configuration Properties* -> *Linker* -> *Command Line*. This will show you all options with which your IDE invokes the compiler and linker.

The mere fact that the IDE uses so many options should tell you that it's not using the tools' defaults.

If you go to the command line and invoke the compiler and linker with the same options shown in the IDE, then the resulting executable should be 100% identical.

Answer (score 2):

Compiling in VS with the `/MTd` option is building your program with multi-threaded debug libraries in the final executable, which will cause a size increase in your binary for those extra objects.

The compile command of just the source file will not result in any additional object code being linked, and will result in a smaller exe.

See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx) for further reference

When I use the same source code, with the same compiler options, I get a final size of 391K.
From the command line, I get the following:

```
cl MyProg.cpp -> 31K
cl /MTd MyProg.cpp -> 137K
```

If you include some of the other options that the IDE is including for you, then you get something like this:

```
cl /MTd /Gm /ZI /EHsc MyProg.cpp -> 378K
```

It's simply a matter of the difference between the build commands that is causing your difference.

Comment: I did this option because i wanted to be portable, if i compile the code under console it is portable to other pc's and windows xp and its small, to be portable exe compiled with the ide i must select this option, but the size is bigger, this is what i can't understand. How i can make the same size using the ide and be portable like the one compiled under the console. I'm sorry for not including this in my question.

Comment: Is Incremental Linking also enabled by default? I guess that could add a bit but not too much (+10K???)

Comment: Both of them are "portable", you just need to decide if you want to include VC++ debug libraries in your final executable. If you don't care about that, use the command-line compiled version. Likewise, you can also try the `/MDd` option, which will rely on DLL's to provide that capability. The downside is, if the target machine is missing those DLL's, you will get a runtime error.

Comment: just tried with example above; cl hello.c => 32Kb cl /MTd hello.c => 145 KB (but I am using C++ compiler 16.00.40219.01 VStudio 2013) I wonder what else is different?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i was testing and i wanted to understand in more depth what's going in the exe. Using /MDd option does not port to XP or other win 7 (i assume only the ones that i made the test). When compiling it under console the size is minimum and its portable on all machines that i tested. When using the option in the IDE is also portable but the size is very big. I wanted to know why it is including this code, when its not needed. You say it icludes the VC++ debug libs, but compiled under console it does not included but its still portable xD interesting.